# If i use OpenStreetMaps offline maps in my offline APP, should i show "openstreetmap" license text on the maps?

Tags: android, licensing, openstreetmap

i'm developing a commercial android app that shows a offline map (whithout requiring internet connexion.) This map is a binary vector map that it is rendericed to display the map offline.

The binary map is generated from a OpenStreetMap xml map.

This app will have cost, it's for a commercial project.

SHould i put something like `"OpenStreetMap ©"` in the mapview when i'm displaying the map ?

i can't find any clear guide about that on openstreetmaps website.

Comment: Just follow their copyright and license guidelines: http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright

Comment: i can't understand them, they are very confusing. I'm using a binary offline map, i dnt use their servers. Also my english skills are poor... a little help will be apreciated

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer [this link *I would like to use OpenStreetMap maps. How should I credit you*](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Legal_FAQ#3a._I_would_like_to_use_OpenStreetMap_maps._How_should_I_credit_you.3F):

- Their requested attribution is "© OpenStreetMap contributors".
- Because OpenStreetMap is its contributors, you may omit the word "contributors" if space is limited.
- Direct your readers to openstreetmap.org (perhaps by expanding 'OpenStreetMap' to this full address), to opendatacommons.org

**Where to put it**

- For a browsable electronic map (e.g. embedded in a web page or mobile phone application), the credit should appear in the corner of the map, as commonly seen with map APIs/libraries such as Google Maps, or an about box/page.

[image]

Comment: that license terms are when you are using their ONLINE osm tiles, but here i'm using offline binary maps, so i'm not using their servers... this is confusing.

Comment: I think you should still give credit to OpenStreetMap. You might be interested in looking into this discussion: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/16377/commercial-use-of-open-street-tiles  If you are too confused, just raise a question here: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/ask/

Comment: Yes, you should still give credit. The licence is for their **data** not their servers. If you follow techenthusiast's summary, I think everyone will be happy.

Comment: @AndroidUser99: It's about the database, the images (the geodata, the map) for what you have to give contribution first-hand. Not if it's online or not (accessing other persons online-services might come with additional usage-terms *next* to copyright). These requirements here are mainly based on copyright (not on right-to-use-some-others-server).